# FindViewById returns null on custom relative layout

Tags: android, android-custom-view, android-relativelayout

In init method, findViewById returns null on R.id.disable_view_content.

```
public class DisableView extends RelativeLayout {

    private View content;
    private View disableView;
    private int disableBackgroundColor;
    private boolean isEnabled;

    public DisableView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public DisableView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        obtainAttributes(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public DisableView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        obtainAttributes(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    public DisableView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
        obtainAttributes(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    private void obtainAttributes(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet) {
        TypedArray typedArray = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(attributeSet, R.styleable.DisableView, 0, 0);
        disableBackgroundColor = typedArray.getColor(R.styleable.DisableView_disableBackground, 0x00000000);
        isEnabled = typedArray.getBoolean(R.styleable.DisableView_enabled, false);
        typedArray.recycle();
    }

    private void init() {
        content = findViewById(R.id.disable_view_content);
        disableView = new View(getContext());
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_TOP, R.id.disable_view_content);
        lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_BOTTOM, R.id.disable_view_content);
        lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_LEFT, R.id.disable_view_content);
        lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_TOP, R.id.disable_view_content);
        disableView.setBackgroundResource(disableBackgroundColor);
        disableView.setLayoutParams(lp);
        setEnabled(isEnabled);
    }

    public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        content.setEnabled(enabled);
        if(enabled) disableView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        else disableView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

Here's xml

```
<com....view.common.DisableView
        android:id="@+id/..._disableView_...Disable"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@id/disable_view_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/..._textView_..."
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/shape_rect_green"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingTop="18dp"
                android:paddingBottom="18dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
                android:textSize="@dimen/size_text"
                android:text="@string/..."
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:duplicateParentState="true"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </com....view.common.DisableView>
```

id disable_view_content is in attr.xml

```
<resources>
    <item type="id" name="disable_view_content"/>
</resources>
```

Everything seems fine, view with the id disable_view_content is a direct child of DisableView. But either in edit mode or on app, i get a null pointer because the reference content is null.

Edit: Here's the stack trace:

```
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.setEnabled(boolean)' on a null object reference
            at com....view.common.DisableView.setEnabled(DisableView.java:71)
            at com....view.common.DisableView.init(DisableView.java:67)
            at com....view.common.DisableView.<init>(DisableView.java:35)
```

Answer (score 5):

You are calling `findViewById()` far too early in the View's lifecycle.

Your `init()` is called directly from your constructor, and before you have even created a layout for your own View. At this point in time, your View has no layout and has no children either.

The *earliest* you can access child Views is after one of the [`addView()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#addView(android.view.View)) methods has been called.

Comment: I believe overriding _View.onFinishInflate()_ method would be one of the best places to start handling with child views.

Comment: Cheers.. I suspected something like that. I didn't know that there's a lifecycle called onFinishInflate, better then using addView since there are tons of addViews and I'm not sure which one is used :)